# Conditional Highlighting VBA based on Date

Tags: vba, excel

[image: Sample Workbook]

I made this workbook that works sort of like a program. It takes orders, puts it in a masterlist on a separate sheet, then plots it on a calendar. Using VBA, I want my code to autohighlight the newly /modified input orders. Right now I have to double click the cell to highlight it because Excel doesn't recognize formula changes as a modification. I want to add a time range condition too - when the order is due within 14 days I want the highlight to be red, but 14 days or more is still yellow. Right now my code goes like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim c As Range
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B9:AE53")) Is Nothing Then
    For Each c In Intersect(Target, Range("B9:AE53"))
        Target.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    Next c
End If
End Sub
```

Is it doable? How do I modify my code?

[Same workbook, different issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44836440/auto-highlight-newly-input-cells-using-vba)

Comment: I think this is can be done with conditional formatting.

Comment: Isn't this the same thing that you are already asking in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44836440/auto-highlight-newly-input-cells-using-vba

Comment: @RomcelGeluz I have to reset the highlights daily (i made a command button) so conditional formatting is out.

Comment: Why are you asking the same question twice?

Comment: @teylyn the other one was about auto highlighting, not double clicking to highlight. This, on the other hand, is about the conditions for highlighting.

Comment: @teylyn I was told before not to put two topics in one question so I separated them.

Comment: @pnuts neither have been solved so I didn't think linking them would be necessary? Or should I?

Comment: @pnuts Duly noted. Thanks!

Comment: Conditional formatting should be able to work. How i would recommend you to make this work is by usiing the SUM method. if end dateline - current date is more than 14 = yellow else it would be red.

Answer (score 0):

How to do this using formulas:

1) set the cells to be in **DATE** format

2) write a code to show **current date**

3) **end date** - **current date** = **number of days**.

4) conditional formatting. if the number of days is **greater than 14** it would be yellow, else it would turn red.

All these can be done automatically.